# why not double free error in my c++ code?

Tags: c++, double-free

g++ version is `g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)`

My test code is following

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Handle{
    public:
            Handle(int *p, int u):_p(p),use(u){}
            ~Handle(){cout << "delete" << endl; delete _p;}
            void display(){cout << "value : " << *_p << ", use : " << use << endl;}
    private:
            int *_p;
            int use;
    };

    int main()
    {
        //Test case one
        {
        int *i = new int(10);

        Handle *h = new Handle(i, 2);
        Handle *h1 = new Handle(i, 100);

        h->display();
        h1->display();

        delete h;
        delete h1;
        //call ~Handle() two times, means free double times, why don't runtime error??
        }

        //Test case two
        {
            int *a = new int(11);
            Handle h2(a, 23);
            Handle h3(a, 33);

            h2.display();
            h3.display();

            //in this case, will double free error
        }
        cout << "ok" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Just have test case one, the program runs without error, but if I add test two, this program will have double free error. I don't know how this error take place?

Comment: You say `~Handle` is called three times, but it will only be called twice.  Perhaps you should include the output.

Answer (score 3):

The likely reason that you only get a problem with the extra test is that it has a new memory allocation in it.

Many malloc/free new/delete libraries will corrupt their data structures during a double free. This corruption may not be noticed until the next allocation or free operation. This would be your test two.

Some libraries may even run without error. I believe that some versions of Windows implemented a rather slow but robust memory heap handler as a compatibility option in order to not crash older software that had bugs but got lucky.

Answer (score 2):

The destructor for Handle is called twice.  It calls delete on _p.  In both cases _p is pointing to the single instance of a.  Double free of a.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why one of your tests causes a problem and the other does not.  Both are wrong.  `Handle` shouldn't free the pointer if it didn't allocate the pointer.  That's just asking for trouble.